# Migration Tool: Magento 1.9.2.0 To Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I was working on migrating Magento 1.9.2.0 to Magento 2.2.1

I successfully installed migration tool , but when I went to search for `config.xml.dist` file , it was not found in that place, so in this type of condition what should I have to do ?

[image]

looking for key solution , Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using community version

1. Go to folder "your Magento 2 install dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/". There will be folders naming by magento1 versions
2. Open a folder i.e 1.9.2.0
3. You will find the config.xml.dist
4. Copy it and rename the copied file as config.xml
5. set all the details like magento 1x and magento 2x database details, table prefix etc.
6. Then run command.

   ```
    1. php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset 'path to config.xml'

    2. php bin/magento migrate:data --auto 'path to config.xml'
   ```

etc etc

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Comment: what auto param is responsible for?

Comment: I have followed these steps, data not migrated fully, very less products are migrated, and there is not Default attribute set